# Delete all function from database

Tags: sql-server, function

How can I delete all function from my database using sql-script. 
I tried:

```
declare @nm varchar(100)
select @nm = name from sysobjects where type = 'FN'
exec('drop function ' + @nm)
```

And I put in into the loop but it not delete all function. Please help

Comment: Please show us the loop.  Also, when you say "not delete all function" what functions are left?  How many are deleted?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql = @sql + N' DROP FUNCTION ' 
                   + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)) 
                   + N'.' + QUOTENAME(name)
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%';

Exec sp_executesql @sql
GO
```